# How do i store blocks information in my Voxel game?

Tags: unity, c#, procedural-generation, voxels, minecraft-modding

I am trying to make a voxel game.

Voxel games made by blocks and each block has it's own information such as durability, step sounds, strength, ...

How do i store these information inside of blocks? or is it true to save their information inside of themselves.

Do i store them on all blocks instances or static properties?

```c#
public class Block
{

    public virtual float durability
    {
        get
        {
            return 1f;
        }
    }

    public virtual float strength
    {
        get
        {
            return 1f;
        }
    }

    public virtual StepSound stepSound
    {
        get
        {
            return new StepSound ( "stone.ogg" );
        }
    }

}
```

Then create a class by inheriting `Block` class:

```c#
public class BlockDirt : Block
{

    public override float durability
    {
        get
        {
            return 0.5f;
        }
    }

    public override float strength
    {
        get
        {
            return 0.5f;
        }
    }

    public override StepSound stepSound
    {
        get
        {
            return new StepSound ( "dirt.ogg" );
        }
    }

}
```

Now i have all the above properties inside of any `BlockDirt` instances.

But it takes to much memory. just think i have 100 `BlockDirt`.

Or Do i create a base class:

```c#
public class Block
{

}
```

Then inherit it for creating blocks:

```c#
public class BlockDirt : Block
{

    public static StepSound stepSound = new StepSound ( "dirt.ogg" );
    public static float durability = 0.5f;
    public static float strength = 0.5f;

}
```

And use the `BlockDirt` static properties for all `BlockDirt` instances?

I don't know how to get static properties from class instance, but i know i can do it using **Reflection** but it takes more CPU and memory than instance based data.

What should i do?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want to imitate Minecraft, why not *have a look at Minecraft's source?* Modding will teach you a *ton* about this sort of thing.

Comment: Where do i find Minecraft source code? Do you mean Minecraft forge? the source code of the Minecraft Forge is not readable.

Comment: Minecraft Forge's sorce [is open source on github](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge), but no, what I mean is: download the MDK and install it. After opening the project in Eclipse or IntelliJ, under referenced libraries, will be a read-only version of Minecraft's source code.

Comment: Is it decompiled version of Minecraft jar files or is the official source files and contains names correctly? Do you mean create mods for minecraft and learn how it works?

Comment: Names are supplied by MCP and is very comprehensive. I haven't run into a automatically generated name in 1.11 yet.  And you don't have to create mods, my point is you can look at how Minecraft does the thing you want to do and learn from it.

Comment: If you're looking for language specific help (i.e. how to get static properties from class instance, etc), please tag the question with the language you're using. Minecraft is Java, but your `BlockDirt` class declaration is not Java.

Comment: @Draco18s i had a look at minecraft source but it's source code is confusing because of very bad named functions like `a`, `b` function names. How do i detect functions while they don't have descriptive name? So it shows it is a decompiled source of minecraft.

Comment: @Pikalek Thanks for your suggestion. i have added **c#** tag. the code written in c#. but it is not important, i just need a solution for this.

Comment: This sounds like a job for [The Flyweight Pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/flyweight.html). ;)

Comment: @DMGregory I don't read it completely but as i seen the pattern stores information on each of Tree (As blocks), but it takes to much memory form me!

Comment: You stopped reading too early. ;)

Comment: I don't have time to read this. can you give me the meaning of it? (if can't, i will read it tomorrow)

Comment: *`i had a look at minecraft source but it's source code is confusing because of very bad named functions like a, b function names`* Then you didn't install a Forge development environment properly, like I told you to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you take a look at the [flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). It allows you to use objects such as tiles or blocks in very large numbers when a simple repeated representation would use an unacceptable amount of memory. The principle is well represented by this picture :

[image]

You basically have one object **Tree** that is instanciated and which defines all shared attributes between trees. You then just have to create position parameters to tell the engine where to display this single object.

Here is the full [example](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/flyweight.html) applied to your problem if you want to know more.

**EDIT :** A few concrete examples :

- Creating Aliens on Unity (C#), comparing memory use. [link](http://www.habrador.com/tutorials/programming-patterns/2-flyweight-pattern/)
- Counter-Strike example (JAVA), reuse of the player models. [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flyweight-design-pattern/)
- A live explaination by a youtuber (JAVA). [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vV-R2926ss)

I put Java examples as Java is pretty similar to C# in its syntax and structure. I'm sure you can find more example online, and perhaps better one.

Comment: Thanks, this is a cool design pattern. but it would be better to say how do i implement it in Unity game engine using c#?

Comment: The design pattern simply outlines the principle, the implementation is really up to you. I won't give you the full implementation as I don't know your game and simply don't have the time but I'll update my answer to include examples :)

Comment: Added, tell me if you need further explaination !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Minecraft did it, but very long ago, I once wrote a Minecraft clone. You could have a look on how I did it.

- There is [a block model](https://github.com/mcourteaux/CraftMania/blob/master/CraftMania/src/org/craftmania/blocks/DefaultBlockBrush.java), storing all the details about that type of block you want. The model has an ID. Every [block in the world](https://github.com/mcourteaux/CraftMania/blob/master/CraftMania/src/org/craftmania/blocks/DefaultBlock.java) declares of which type it is by holding this model ID.
- [Block serialisation model](https://github.com/mcourteaux/CraftMania/blob/master/CraftMania/src/org/craftmania/world/ChunkData.java#L24).

I am definitely not saying that this is how you should do it, or this is a good way to do it, but it worked. Note that I was probably only 17 back then and had little to no experience with this.